# Spring Hibernate: EntityExistsException when storing n:m table value with combiend Priamry Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

So my second post. This time i worked on a passion project of mine, which turned out to be far more complicated than I expected and again I need some help.

I have two enitites: Gamestate and User.

Users are supposed to be able to join multiple Games(/gamestates). Games(/gamestates) are supposed to have muliple people join them. So therefore it is represented as a N:M Relation.

Depending on who joins and when they join they are supposed to have different roles, giving them different rights in the app. Which means I needed an N:M Relation with custom fields and therefore I had to model the relation table myself. That's as far as I have come.

Abstract Model:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public abstract class AbstractModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    protected String identifier;
}
```

User

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class User extends AbstractModel{

    private String nickName;
    private UserRole role;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private LoginInformation loginInformation;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "gameState")
    private List<UserGameState> userGameStates = new ArrayList<>();

    //DTO Constructor
    public User(UserDTO userDTO){
        this.identifier = Optional.ofNullable(userDTO.getIdentifier())
                .orElse(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        this.nickName = userDTO.getNickName() == null ? "": userDTO.getNickName();
        this.role = UserRole.valueOf(userDTO.getRole());

        this.loginInformation = null;
        if(userDTO.getLoginInformation() != null) {
            setLoginInformation(new LoginInformation(userDTO.getLoginInformation()));
        } else {
            setLoginInformation(new LoginInformation());
        }

        (userDTO.getUserGameStates() == null ? new ArrayList<GameStateDTO>() : userDTO.getUserGameStates())
                .stream()
                .map(x -> new UserGameState((UserGameStateDTO) x))
                .forEach(this::addUserGameState);
    }
```

GameState

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class GameState extends AbstractModel{
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String image;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserGameState> userGameStates = new ArrayList<>();

    //DTO Constructor
    public GameState(GameStateDTO gameStateDTO){
        this.identifier = Optional.ofNullable(gameStateDTO.getIdentifier())
                .orElse(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        this.name = gameStateDTO.getName() == null ? "": gameStateDTO.getName();
        this.description = gameStateDTO.getDescription() == null ? "": gameStateDTO.getDescription();
        this.image = gameStateDTO.getImage() == null ? "": gameStateDTO.getImage();

        (gameStateDTO.getUserGameStates() == null ? new ArrayList<UserDTO>() : gameStateDTO.getUserGameStates())
                .stream()
                .map(x -> new UserGameState((UserGameStateDTO) x))
                .forEach(this::addUserGameState);
    }
    //----------------------1:1 Relationship Methods----------------------
    //----------------------1:N Relationship Methods----------------------
    public void addUserGameState(UserGameState userGameState) {
        if (userGameStates.contains(userGameState)) {
            return;
        }
        userGameStates.add(userGameState);
        userGameState.setGameState(this);
    }

    public void removeUserGameState(UserGameState userGameState) {
        if (!userGameStates.contains(userGameState)) {
            return;
        }
        userGameState.setGameState(null);
        userGameStates.remove(userGameState);
    }
    //----------------------N:1 Relationship Methods----------------------
    //----------------------N:M Relationship Methods----------------------
}
```

UserGameSatet (Custom N:M Table)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserGameState{

    @EmbeddedId
    private User_GameState_PK id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("user_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("gameState_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "GAMESTATE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private GameState gameState;

    //add Role later

    public UserGameState(User u, GameState gs) {
        // create primary key
        this.id = new User_GameState_PK(u.getId(), gs.getId());

        // initialize attributes
        setUser(u);
        setGameState(gs);

    }


    public UserGameState(UserGameStateDTO userGameStateDTO){
        //this.id =
        this.user = null;
        this.gameState = null;
    }



    //----------------------1:1 Relationship Methods----------------------
    //----------------------1:N Relationship Methods----------------------
    //----------------------N:1 Relationship Methods----------------------
    public void setUser(User user) {
        if (Objects.equals(this.user, user)) {
            return;
        }

        User oldUser = this.user;
        this.user = user;

        if (oldUser != null) {
            oldUser.removeUserGameState(this);
        }

        if (user != null) {
            user.addUserGameState(this);
        }
    }

    public void setGameState(GameState gameState) {
        if (Objects.equals(this.gameState, gameState)) {
            return;
        }

        GameState oldGameState = this.gameState;
        this.gameState = gameState;

        if (oldGameState != null) {
            oldGameState.removeUserGameState(this);
        }

        if (oldGameState != null) {
            oldGameState.addUserGameState(this);
        }
    }
    //----------------------N:M Relationship Methods----------------------
}
```

User_GameState_PK (Combined Key)

```
@Embeddable
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User_GameState_PK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long user_id;

    @Column(name = "GAMESTATE_ID")
    private Long gameState_id;

    public User_GameState_PK(long user_id, long gameState_id){
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.gameState_id = gameState_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        User_GameState_PK that = (User_GameState_PK) o;
        return Objects.equals(user_id, that.user_id) &&
                Objects.equals(gameState_id, that.gameState_id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(user_id, gameState_id);
    }
}
```

The method saving the Connection in my Service

(both GameState and User are already instantiated, and the method gets the identifier of both objects, retrieving them from the database and adding the relation between them.)

```
    public Optional<GameStateDTO> addUserToGameState(String identifierGS, String identifierU) {
        GameState gameState = gameStateRepo.findByIdentifier(identifierGS)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("GameState ID has no according GameState."));
        User user = userRepo.findByIdentifier(identifierU)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("User ID has no according User."));

        //Custom N:M Connection Part
        UserGameState connection = new UserGameState(user, gameState);
        userGameStateRepo.save(connection);

        return Optional.of(gameState)
                .map(m -> convertModelIntoDTO(m));
    }
```

I managed to set the N:M table up, together with its combined key. I tested it with simple CRUD Routes, and they worked.

Next I tried to set up some routes so that people could actually join a game(/gamestate) at which point it throws the following exception upon saving.

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.Astralis.backend.model.UserGameState#User_GameState_PK(user_id=1, gameState_id=7)]
```

After reading through some posts on stackoverflow I tried out changing the Cascadetype to .MERGE, which resulted in this exception.

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: ...
```

Really I am lost here, it feels like if I use .PERSIST, Hibernate complaines that it copies itself while saving the Relation. While if I change it to .MERGE, it complaines that the value isn't already present in the first place.

I am more than thankfull for any breadcrumb bringing me closer to a solution, as this turned out to be a gigantic roadblock for the project, and I have tried out everything that I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few more days of searching I managed to solve it.

For this I first remade a guide's project in with the data structure from the guide and the service/controller structure of my project. Testing if it would work, and as it did I just started comparing the models with each other and tried all different possibilities out, to find out what is actually causing the issues.

The used guide is this one: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

I had six Copy&Paste (kinda) mistakes that caused Hibernate to falsely associate table columns with each other. These were:

1. in User:

```
...

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "user",// changed from gameState to user
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserGameState> userGameStates = new ArrayList<>();

...
```

2. in GameState the reverse:

```
...

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "gameState",// changed from user to gameState
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserGameState> userGameStates = new ArrayList<>();

...
```

3&4. The JoinColumn Annotations were unnecessary, seemingly I combiend multiple guides into one project. This caused then even more issues:

```
...

    @ManyToOne(
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("user_id")
    //@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false) //this one removed
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("gameState_id")
    //@JoinColumn(name = "GAMESTATE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false) //this one removed
    private GameState gameState;

...
```

5&6. Two minor copy&paste mistakes, in the "continuity keeper" methods in UserGameState:

```
...


    public void setGameState(GameState gameState) {
        if (Objects.equals(this.gameState, gameState)) {
            return;
        }

        GameState oldGameState = this.gameState;
        this.gameState = gameState;

        if (oldGameState != null) {
            oldGameState.removeUserGameState(this);
        }

        //I copied the previous if block, and replaced the remove... with add...
        //But I didn't change the oldGameState to gameState.
        //This didn't throw any errors, and actually it still created the relations         properly, but I am pretty sure it would cause issues further down the line.
        if (gameState != null) {
            gameState.addUserGameState(this);
        }
    }
...
```

So how does this work now:
As before, when the route with the Identifiers for the connected GameState and User is called, the service "addUserToGameState" is called, getting the models with the given Identifiers.

```
...
    public Optional<GameStateDTO> addUserToGameState(String identifierGS, String identifierU) {
        GameState gameState = gameStateRepo.findByIdentifier(identifierGS)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("GameState ID has no according GameState."));
        User user = userRepo.findByIdentifier(identifierU)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("User ID has no according User."));

        //Custom N:M Connection Part
        UserGameState connection = new UserGameState(user, gameState);

        return Optional.of(gameState)
                .map(m -> convertModelIntoDTO(m));
    }
...
```

After that the UserGameState cosntructer is called, which sets and creates the combined key and calls the setter methods for the related User/GameState fields.

```
...
    public UserGameState(User u, GameState gs) {
        // create primary key
        this.id = new User_GameState_PK(u.getId(), gs.getId());

        // initialize attributes
        setUser(u);
        setGameState(gs);

    }
...
```

I wrote the setters in a way, that they at the same time, check the added models for relationship consistency issues, and adjust their fields according to if they are newly edited or replaced.

```
...
    public void setUser(User user) {
        if (Objects.equals(this.user, user)) {
            return;
        }

        User oldUser = this.user;
        this.user = user;

        if (oldUser != null) {
            oldUser.removeUserGameState(this);
        }

        if (user != null) {
            user.addUserGameState(this);
        }
    }

    public void setGameState(GameState gameState) {
        if (Objects.equals(this.gameState, gameState)) {
            return;
        }

        GameState oldGameState = this.gameState;
        this.gameState = gameState;

        if (oldGameState != null) {
            oldGameState.removeUserGameState(this);
        }

        if (gameState != null) {//copy paste error
            gameState.addUserGameState(this);
        }
    }
...
```